# How to fix error insert value ASP to SQL "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value..."

Tags: sql, asp.net

[image]

Info error:

Code detail:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Start Time (Ngày khởi chiếu)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </div>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTime" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" textmode="Date"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Stop Time (Ngày kết thúc)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </div>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtStopTime" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" textmode="Date"/>
    </div>
</div>

protected void btnThem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Movie m = new Movie();
        m.title = txtTitle.Text;
        m.start_time = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartTime.Text);
        m.stop_time = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStopTime.Text);

public void AddMovie(Movie m)
{
    con.Open();
    string rq = "INSERT INTO Movies([title],[start_time],[stop_time],[genre],[actor],[director]," +
        "[duration],[version],[production],[price],[movie_detail],[image_thumb])" +
        " VALUES(@title,@starttime,@stoptime,@genre,@actor,@director,@duration,@version,@production," +
        "@price,@moviedetail,@imagethumb)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(rq, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", m.title);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("starttime",m.start_time.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("stoptime", m.stop_time.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd"));
```

I get the following error while insert a value `datetime` in SQL:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

I searched but could not fix it.

Comment: what's the table definition for you Movies table? specifically, what are start_time and stop_time defined as?  datetime, smalldatetime, ?

Comment: Can you try printing out `m.start_time` and `m_stop_time` to the console to see what they look like? Or use a breakpoint, etc.

Comment: Also try formatting the date like `mm/dd/yyyy`. SQL can be fussy on those things

Comment: sql m.start_time defined as datetime-

Comment: public Movie()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime start_time { get; set; }
    public DateTime stop_time { get; set; }

Comment: check the numeric date format section, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms180878(v=sql.105)#StringLiteralDateandTimeFormats

Comment: +  m.stop_time {12/26/2018 12:00:00 AM} System.DateTime

Comment: yes i  will try it

Comment: thanks all. i fix done. I use .ToShortDateString